# EGL Group Permissions Add/Manage

Tags: php, mysql, customization

For those of you that have dealt with EGL (Elite Gaming Ladders) Tournament & Ladders script... I'm having a problem figuring out how to add new group permissions for customized mods I've made. I've created a new type of "General Rules" mod that I would like to store the permission as shown:

```
case "select_genrules";
    if($group['genrules_manager']=="yes"){
        include("./includes/rules.php");
        select_genrules();
    }else{
        return warning("<b>" . LANG_WARNING_NO_PERMISSIONS_TO_ACCESS_PAGE . " </b>");
    }
    break;
```

where "genrules_manager" formatted the same as all of the others is added to the group_permissions set. I added it to the groups_permissions table and it actually does show in the list of permissions in the ACP under the category "Misc" but I would like to add "Lang" so that it doesn't just say "genrules_manager" etc... Any help as to how to access/modify those keys in the admincp/includes/addmembergroup.php and admincp/includes/managemembergroup.php would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually found in groups.php under the functions addmembergroup and editmembergroup. You will need to add a key that links to the "lang" you have written in admincp/language/english.php like so:

```
if($key=='genrules_manager'){$descr='' . LANG_GRO_PERMISSIONS_DESCR_GENRULES_MANAGER . ''; $site .= group_radio($key, $value, $descr);}
```

It has to be done in both functions in order for you to see when adding and editing. Simply place it inline with the keys under whichever category you'd like...

Comment: Thats exactly waht I was looking for Thank You!